# Configuration array: how to hook in before each Sass compilation #16075

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, sass-loader

In webpack 4.x

I have an array of configs for a number of sites sharing same design structures.
On build action I'd like to enter the process just before the Sass compiler is running to be able to change a file content.

Using sass-loader options or webpack-shell-plugin before hook didn't help at all

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: "change a file content" – what exactly would you change?

Comment: each project has a number of theme files - sass modules and a selected.sass file which should be updated with the selected theme content; so rewriting that selected.sass during webpack build, before compiler starts sass to css; I will try a custom loader and will see how that goes